# Intercepting calls to Mailer actions

Tags: java, email, playframework

Is there a way to intercept calls to a [Play Mailer class](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/current/emails#mvc)?

I would like to log all emails my application sends. I'd like to access the mailer method parameters and method name, and log all these.

I have tried using @With, but my @Before method is not called:

```
@With(EmailInterceptor.class)
public class Mails extends Mailer {

    public static void welcome(User user) {
        setSubject("Welcome to my app");
        setFrom("Me <me@domain.com>");
        addRecipient(user.email);

        Mailer.send(user);
    }
}

public final class EmailInterceptor extends UserAwareControllerBase {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerHelper.getLogger();

    @Before
    public void logEmail(){
        String email = getUser() == null ? "<null>" : getUser().email;
        logger.info("Sending email to " + email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no intercepts for Mailer. Check the https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/ActionInvoker.java. Go to line 142, that clearly indicate only Controller will get intercepts.

Comment: Too bad. For now I'll accept your answer and copy-paste the logging code to all mail methods ... hoping sometime in the future this will change.

Comment: I think there is a workaround, just wrap the Mailer.send(...) call with a static method defined in your Mails class. Put that logic you want to intercept into that method, and call that method instead of Mailer.send. That should an easy way to do what you want